# mysqlimport speed ----tab delimited dump files vs SQL format files

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

Generating tab delimited dump files with **mysqldump** is known to be much faster than creating SQL format files.  What about **mysqlimport**?  Is import from tab delimited dump files, using **mysqlimport**, any faster than import from SQL format files?

I ran a somewhat small experiment and I did not see any appreciable difference.

Comment: You might like my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `LOAD DATA INFILE` can be *much* faster than running `INSERT` statements.

For small sets, we won't see an appreciable difference.

With larger sets, the difference becomes apparent.

With *very large* sets, we often want to break up an `LOAD DATA INFILE` import into manageable, reasonably sized chunks. (One of the advantages of that is it avoids blowing out the rollback space in ibdata1 for an extremely large transaction.)

NOTE: `mysqlimport` is a command line interface for MySQL `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement.